# scala: override implicit var in constructor, in both parent class and child class?

Tags: scala

i have a class that takes an implicit parameter which is used by functions called inside class methods. i want to be able to either override that implicit parameter and have both the class and its inherited parent class have a reference to the same new implicit object.

making the Parent implicit a var and setting that to a new value successfully overrides the implicit in the parent, but not the child.

(this is similar to [scala: override implicit parameter to constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5962122/scala-override-implicit-parameter-to-constructor), except there is the added restriction that the override affect both child class and parent class.)

for example:

```
def outside(implicit x: Boolean) {
  println(x)
}

class Parent(implicit var x: Boolean) {
  def setImplicit() {
    x = true
  }

  def callOutside {
    outside
  }
}

class Child(implicit x: Boolean) extends Parent {
  override def callOutside {
    outside
  }
}
```

and then:

```
scala> val a = new Parent()(false)
a: Parent = Parent@c351f6d

scala> a.callOutside
false

scala> a.setImplicit()

scala> a.callOutside
true // <-- sees the new implicit correctly


scala> val b = new Child()(false)
b: Child = Child@68331dd0

scala> b.callOutside
false

scala> b.setImplicit()

scala> b.callOutside
false // <-- wrong, desire "true" instead
```

is there any way to get the desired behavior? doing things like making both Parent and Child implicit be a var doesn't seem to work. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could just

```
class Parent(x0: Boolean) {
  implicit var x = x0
  ...
}
```

if you didn't really need the class parameter to be implicit.  I'll assume that you do.

One alternative is to put the implicits on the companion object.  Like so:

```
class Parent(x0: Boolean) {
  implicit var x = x0
  def setImplicit { x = true }
  def outsideCall { outside }
}
object Parent {
  def apply(implicit x: Boolean) = new Parent(x)
}

class Child(x0: Boolean) extends Parent(x0) {
  def callOutside { outside }
}
object Child {
  def apply(implicit x: Boolean) = new Child(x)
}
```

Alternatively, you could create a private main constructor for Child (decorated in some way so it's not ambiguous with the implicit) and use an implicit on a secondary constructor:

```
class Child private (b: Boolean, u: Unit) extends Parent()(b) {
  def this()(implicit x: Boolean) = this(x,())
  def callOutside { outside }
}
```